# Drawing symmetrical images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation, plugin

Does anyone know of any programs or plugins for photoshop (or gimp, even) to make drawing symmetrical images easier? I am especially looking for the ability to make multiple views, as in a two-surface, three-surface (triangle), four surface (plus sign), five surface (star). Drawing on any one surface would replicate onto each surface

Does such a program exist? I've been checking google, but haven't had any success. I'm not sure exactly what I am looking for.

I'm sure theres one out there, I remember using one back on a windows 95 machine that had a line down the middle. Drawing on one side automatically drew on the other as well.

Currently I'm doing work on one corner, copy/pasting it three times and rotating it. It works, but it's just incredibly tedious. And I don't know of a quicker way than that.

Comment: http://www.sumopaint.com does this. It's not a photoshop plugin, so  I didn't make it an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to mirror paths as you draw them in Photoshop? (For drawing symmetric shapes.)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-there-a-way-to-mirror-paths-as-you-draw-them-in-photoshop-for-drawing-symmet)

Comment: @e100: It is duplicate, but the core questions asks for both plugins and seperate apps. I'm going to leave it be, but the community can still vote as a dupe or to close it. @luckycypher: The OP asked for applications as well, not just plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that Corel 12 does this.

http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1166553885783#versionTabview=tab0&tabview=tab1

Answer (score 3):

Try playing around with Symbols in Illustrator.  You won't get a real-time "drawing *here* and watching it duplicated *there*" experience, but you can get easy symmetry.

1. Draw your base shape that you want to work with.  You don't have to outline it, but I find it makes the alignment easier.  (It will be easy to change later anyway).

   [image: I'm using a simple square]
2. Do whatever rotating & aligning you want.  (I'm just making a simple 90° rotated 4-square pattern).

   [image: More squares]
3. Double-click any instance of your Symbol to "edit the definition".  (This is fancy Illustrator-speak for "change the base art")

   [image: Symbol editing]
4. When you are finished editing a Symbol instance, your changes will be automatically applied to all of the other instances of the same.

   [image: Done!]

This same workflow could be applied to triangles, squares, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is its called Manga Studio
you can make symmetrical drawings and some other stuff

Comment: Welcome to GD! Can you maybe explain why you recommend this program? Is it paid? What's the advantage of using it?