# Moving 2 images apart from eachother

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I'm trying to know how to move 2 of the exact same images at the same time, and move them apart from each other. One moves to the left, while the other moves to the right, at the same time. I want them to be the same space away from each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to mirror paths as you draw them in Photoshop? (For drawing symmetric shapes.)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-there-a-way-to-mirror-paths-as-you-draw-them-in-photoshop-for-drawing-symme)

Comment: Or.. Just move them. If that or manually moving your images doesn't answer your question you need to be more specific.

Comment: I was about to post an answer with the same method as [@Ryan's answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/74477/52050), so I won't bother now, but [here is the screen recording I was going to post](http://recordit.co/3Rk6kobmkU).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a smart object
2. Duplicate it
3. Flip it along the axis you want to transpose the objects

Then you could effectively move things at the same time.

Original:

[image]

Original Smart Object:

[image]

Move and to make it more obvious lets add a few other squares too:

[image]

And the final symmetrical result:

[image]

Beyond this you would need to look at plugins, other apps, or scripting.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible without scripting and adding functionality to Photoshop.

In that case you could create a "constraint" style system that permitted the edge of one to move the edge of another a similar distance from a central point.

Until you learn enough JavaScript and photoshop to do this, instead, you'll have to manually pick one image, move it, then move the other the equivalent to discover the ideal balance and spacing you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least three objects selected. Then select under layers/distribute.

or
Have smart guides turned on under View/show/smart guides 
and Snap to guide turned on View/snap to/guides

You will me able to move a single object and a guide with measurement will appear. It will snap when evenly distributed

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever little trick!