# Is there anyway to mirror paths as you draw them in GIMP? (for symmetric shapes)

Tags: gimp, path

To draw symmetric shapes, is there anyway to mirror shapes just like the mirror modifier in Blender (i.e creating a completely symmetric half by just drawing one half of the path)?

It is very difficult to create a path which is totally symmetrical manually. I found a [similar question for Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/is-there-a-way-to-mirror-paths-as-you-draw-them-in-photoshop-for-drawing-symme), but the answer there is not applicable for GIMP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with paths directly, but with brushes certainly.

Click *Windows > Dockable Dialogs > Symmetry Painting*. Choose the symmetry you want, and paint. It is possible to create a path and then stroke it with a brush, and then the symmetry painting settings will apply.

Example

[image]

If instead you want to create vector graphics, perhaps have a look at Inkscape. Like GIMP it's also free and Open Source. It has a mirror symmetry path effect

Comment: Then the created symmetric image in a new layer can be selected by select by color tool and then the selection can be converted to a path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`path-mirror`](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#path-mirror) script:

> This script mirrors all strokes in a path across a specified vertical or horizontal axis. When used with the "merge" option, the resulting path contains the strokes from the source path and their mirrored versions. Furthermore, if the start or end point of an open stroke remain the same, the source and mirrored strokes are connected into one single stroke. If both start and end remain the same, the resulting stroke is closed.